# LINQ using a where clause to loop through a different array in c#

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to return a list of names that do not exist in `report`. However I am not sure how to loop properly through  `IEnumerable<string> names` using a LINQ. Is there a way to loop through another array using LINQ ?

```
    private class Report
        {
            public string UserName { get; set; }
            public string city { get; set; }
            public string image { get; set; }
        }


  List<Report>report = await _service(id).ConfigureAwait(false);
  IEnumerable<string> names = await _names(id).ConfigureAwait(false);

// only want to get list of names that do not exist in report

 var newList = reports.Where(x => x.UserName.Where(i => != names)); // doesn't work
```

Comment: I would struct names as a Hashset or Dictionary to prevent O(n^2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Contains method. Try like:

```
var newList = reports.Where(x => !names.Contains(x.UserName)));
```

Answer (score 1):

`only want to get list of names that do not exist in report`

You want to query on `names` then, to get names back that don't exist.

```
var newList = names.Where(x => !reports.Any(xx => xx.UserName == x));
```

Comment: You may also want to add a string.equals(xx, xx.UserName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) check instead of a straight equals

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var newList = names.Where(n => reports.Any(r => r.UserName != n));
```